# WalletConnect library not performing transaction also dependency not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, blockchain, wallet-connect

I want to perform a transaction in my app using wallet connect library. Connect button is working fine, but when I try to perform a transaction, it redirected to metamask, but nothing happens. No dialog appears.

Has anyone found any solution? Also when I install this dependency on another project and try to run the project it's throwing an error. Can anybody help me

[This is the error I'm getting while compiling the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dljgP.png)

Comment: Model to send transaction, you probably have parameters wrong:
https://github.com/jemshit/WalletConnect/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/walletconnect/sample/DAppFragment.kt#L337